# why cursors instead of for loop in java collections

Tags: java, loops, collections

I am a java developer, I know cursor concept is the replacement of Pointers in c,c++.

But i didn't understand how cursor was working in background.

To get values in array 
we are using

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{
 System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

but if we go to cursor for collections

```
     Iterator itr = array.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
     Object element = itr.next();
     System.out.print(element + " ");
  }
```

why we didn't go to forloop to print the element instead of cursors?

Comment: well, you can do it with a `foreach loop` or a `for loop` aswell.

Comment: The `i++` approach is particularly bad with some collections, like linked lists where it without have O(n^2) perf. Or in lazy Iterables that don't know their size when the iteration starts.

Comment: I can able to do functions like set,add,remove in both Using for loop and Cursors.  My Question is Why in java Cursors are preferred more than for-loops. What kind of background java is having for cursors to hold the reference of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as in

```
for (Object obj  : array) {
     System.out.print(obj + " ");
}
```

There are different uses depending upon what you want to do.  The Foreach can not update the element, but the iterator can.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use for loop, but if you are using for loop and changed elements in the list, your program will throw ConcurrentModificationException. In this case cursor would work.

Comment: I read through the documentation of ConcurrentModificationException in Oracle docs. It shows the exception may not thrown quietly. if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over another collection iterator(fail-fast iterator), it will throw the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you just want to display the values in that object, then you can go for that array loop, but if you are trying to modify that object, like setting a new value to a certain object then you better go for cursor because you can modify the object and also it's pretty useful if involves in a database

Comment: I can Understand your view,he We are using cursor in database for getting data. Currently I can able to set,add and remove the collection (ArrayList,LinkedList) both using for loop and cursors . My Question is Why in java Cursors are preferred more than for-loops. What kind of background java is having for cursors to hold the reference of the list

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
         array.add("a");
         array.add("b");
         array.add("c");
         array.add("d");
         array.add("e");
         for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.get(i));
         }
```